# Adding Intellisense in VSCode

Tags: intellisense, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I checked several post before asking but didn't find a simple answer.
I am adding a new language extension in VSCode. This language is a proprietary which is quite basic.
Colorization and snippets are done already.
But now I am stuck with intellisense.

I did it already for Sublime and it was pretty simple: add a file mylanguage.sublime-completions
I didn't find the equivalent with VSCode.

Is it an easy way?
I saw some answers related to Typings and installed on VSCode the extension Typing Installer but I dont know how to use it.
I installed Typings also by doing this: npm install -g typings
but again i don't know how to use it :(

Would be glad if somebody could unstuck me !

Kaniass

Answer (score 3):

You may want to have a look at [CompletionItemProvider](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#CompletionItemProvider), i.e. implement that interface and register it with your extensions via `registerCompletionItemProvider`

An extension which provides IntelliSense based on gtags and is not that huge so that you can see how it works could be [C++ Intellisense](https://github.com/austin-----/code-gnu-global)

Comment: Thank you for taking some time to answer.
The point is the solution looks there is coding to do!
And......I am not a coder :)

Comment: @Kaniass Yes, code will be required to add additional features, like auto-complete and intellisense.  However, VSCode has a "default" auto-complete that might work well enough for you.  If your extension doesn't provide a CompletionItemProvider, VSCode will attempt to offer its own list, based on what's already in the current document.

Comment: For clarity, CompletionItemProvider is used for the auto-complete feature, which @DAXaholic deduced (correctly, I think) the OP was really asking for.  Intellisense, which is a bit more detailed and interactive, is provided by the SignatureHelpProvider.